# iPhone image generated locally using jQuery plugin in UIWebView, need to convert to UIImage

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiimage

I generate an image locally in a UIWebView and I would like to save this image in my main bundle after generation so I don't have to perform this operation more than once.  I use a jquery .js source and loadHtmlString command using the following string, with the jquery barcode generator scripts given included:

```
<html>
<head> 
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script> 
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="jquery-barcode-2.0.2.min.js"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<div id="bcTarget1"></div> 
<script>var a = $("#bcTarget1").barcode("Content", "code128", {barWidth: 1 , barHeight: 60, showHRI: false, "output":"bmp" });</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

The image generates fine and I can show it in  a webview, but because the file is generated locally, I am not able to generate a UIImage with a URL in the usual fashion.  I am not very html, js, or jquery saavy; so I am at a loss for what to do here.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this to generate a UIImage from your UIWebView (where view is your UIWebView):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.layer.frame.size, view.opaque, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]); 
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Then this to store the image in your bundle:

```
NSString *fileName = @"somefilename";
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: fileName];   
if([UIImagePNGRepresentation(img) writeToFile: filePath atomically:YES])
        NSLog(@"image stored !");
```